# Websockets/threads/DB connections keep failing on Wildfly

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, wildfly, wildfly-10

I'm currently developing a Java Websocket application that is deployed on Wildfly 10. I cannot post the code, but here's the logic:

Multiple threads poll a database every 5 seconds(select query, reusing a PreparedStatement after closing previous ResultSet) and send via Websocket to all connected clients.

Have configured datasource that connects to MYSQL server (localhost).

The application runs fine until a while later, it crashes and the log is full with 'Unable to get managed connection from datasource' errors. Also, Websocket fails with 'ClosedChannelException'.

Services on the same server that open a connection and close it immediately do work fine. However there are 5-6 threads in the concerned code that must use connections after 5 secs so a thread is given a dedicated connection that is only torn down when the application context is destroyed.

Another thing is when the application fails, it works for a lesser time on disable-enable. Only a reboot gets it to work better.

Same project works without error on Glassfish.

Somehow, Wildfly seems to periodically reset either DB connections, or all TCP connections altogether.

Is there a setting that is relevant to Wildfly's behaviour towards threads? I have verified that only as many threads as are intended are actually created.

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: This application works well on my local machine. When I deploy it on remote server, it works for a while (3 hours max) before failing altogether.

I use Netbeans 8 to compile, if that helps.

Comment: Try to increase the "max-pool-size" into your datasource configuration to 100 (default is 20)    http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/beta500/html/Configuring_JDBC_DataSources.html

Comment: Yes, it is 100. Min-pool-size is 10 and max is 100.

Comment: Did you set the connection-url with "autoReconnect=true" option?

Comment: Yes, have done that. Also, the validate settings have also been set.

Comment: The full stack-trace may help. The NestedSQLException should be caused by anothers

Comment: 'No managed connections available within configured blocking timeout' is the final 'caused by' . .. but hte blocking timeout is 30000ms, and the DB has 500 max_connections value.

Comment: Take a look on Wildfly adminconsole, check the connection pool into the  datasource in runtime section

Comment: Somehow when I enable statistics, the server crashes faster, hangs on the admin console link etc. Basically the connections keep on increasing though I don't create anything new in the code.